# Android API level question - added in 31 but runs on Android 11

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am trying to use LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER, which according to Android Dev documentation was added in API level 31 (Android 12)

My minSdkVersion is 26 for my app

When I put down LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER, Android Studio does NOT complain about my minSdkVersion. Also - my test phone on Android 11 (which I presume is API level 30) runs the app (inclusive of the location functionality) without issue

Can someone please help me understand why Android 11 can run a function making use of the FUSED_PROVIDER despite that being added on in API level 31? Does this imply that phones running down to my minSdkVersion of 26 should be able to handle as well?

Edit:

I just ran the following code on an Android 9 device (spare device I flash downgraded) and the device was able to retrieve the location without error -- not sure how this is happening since Android 9 is API v28

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
```

Comment: Does it compile and run on v26, or just compile?  Those are different scenarios.  The targetSDKVersion controls compiling, not minimum.  But that can still cause failures at runtime on older devices if you try to actually use the functionality on older devices.  You should make sure it actually runs on a version 26 emulator or device  (device is better for location, as emulators can't really emulate location well).

Comment: Please explain what you mean that you "put down LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER".

Comment: @GabeSechan It compiles, but I don't have a v26 device to run it on to test. I am however able to run it on my Android 11 device (which I believe is v30 right?) and the function works as intended - this is why I am confused since I thought the function would not work on Android 11 since FUSED_PROVIDER was added in v31

Comment: @dominicoder I am using it in the requestLocationUpdates function for the first input - provider

Answer (score 0):

> When I put down LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER, Android Studio does NOT complain about my minSdkVersion.

Maybe you need to sync or rebuild or something. It does for me (min 19):

[image]

> Can someone please help me understand why Android 11 can run a function making use of the FUSED_PROVIDER despite that being added on in API level 31?

My guess would be that it works because `FUSED_PROVIDER` is just a String. Once you compile, the system doesn't need or care about the name of the variable, it just cares about the string value, which obviously any version of Android handle. Prior version of Android won't *understand* what "fused" means, but they can certainly handle the string "fused" without exploding.

This is different from a *function*, like `addTestProvider`, which was also added in 31 which will crash your old version of Android quite decidedly.

> Does this imply that phones running down to my minSdkVersion of 26 should be able to handle as well?

I would think so, yes. You can test this easily with the emulator.

Comment: It honestly doesn't do this for me -- and if this were the case, why is it that I can do requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER,...) and I get a location on my Android 11 device?

Comment: I covered that in my answer - `FUSED_PROVIDER` is just a string. When you compile your app, that string constant gets baked in. The system doesn't care about the name "FUSED_PROVIDER" it only cares about the string it holds, which any version of Android can work with.

Comment: I edited my original post - I was able to run the cited code in edit on an Android 9 (API v28) device and it worked. I am happy it works, but I am trying to understand why